# bunzip / bzip2 an entire directory instead of individual files in the directory

Tags: gzip, bzip2

With gunzip its simply `zip -r archive.zip my_dir/`.
Am failing to find an equivalent command for bunzip. Some if found are zipping individual files inside of a directory, but i want one .bzip2 archive.

Comment: `bzip2` only compresses individual files, which is why many people use `tar` to archive the files first. Also, `zip -r` is a completely different command from `gunzip`; one operates on `.zip` files and the other operates on `.gz` files.

Comment: tar -jcvf archive_name.tar.bz2 directory_to_compress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gunzip` is not `zip`.  `zip` is an archiver which handles files and directories.  `gzip`/`gunzip` only compresses a single file or stream of data.

`bzip2` is just like `gzip`, and only compresses a single file or stream of data.  For both `gzip` and `bzip2`, it is traditional to use `tar` as the archiving program, and compressing the output.  In fact that is such a common idiom that `tar` has options to invoke `gzip` or `bzip2` for you.  Do a `man tar`.